# No double / Only one QMessageBox at same time

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, event-loop

In my application, I have the following situation:

1. In a verify-method for inputs of a `QTabWidget`, I'm coming to determine an error for a sub-widget's input.
2. In cause of that I set this sub-widget as the active widget
3. In `showEvent` of this widget I'm firing an `QTimer::singleShot` to a method `onShowEventFinished()` in which I'm going to show a `QMessageBox`
4. After activating the the new sub-widget, I want to show at first the error message from my verify (step 1).

So then the message from verify shows up, but then in cause of my singleShot in step 3 the other one show up over it. I want to show the second one at the earliest, when the first one is closed.
(It's important that the first message shows up at the earliest when the regarding sub widget ist showing.)

Example code:

```
class MySubwidget : public QWidget
{
    // omitted (ctor, etc.)

    protected:
        void showEvent( QShowEvent* e )
        {
             QShowEvent( e );
             QTimer::singleShot( 200, this, SLOT(onShowEventFinished()) );
        };

    private slots:
        void onShowEventFinished()
        {
            bool showEntryHint = false;
            // omitted (some stuff to determine to show an entry hint or not)
            if( showEntryHint )
            {
                QMessageBox t_MessageBox( this );
                // omitted (set up the message box
                t_MessageBox.exec();
            }
        };
};
```

Comment: You can make a field in your class of type `QMessageBox` and use it. It is not nesessary to always use only static methods :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried different ways to solve this with `QMutex`, `QWaitCondition` or `QSemaphore` in a derived class from `QMessageBox` but this doesn't work because the execution of the message box is in the same thread.

This means, when the first message box is started with `QMessageBox::exec()` than `QApplication::processEvents` (called by `QMessageBox`) caused the invokement of my slot and called `QMessageBox::exec()` twice (for the second hint, while the first `exec()` is alive until the first message box is closed).

My currently workaround is now to have a subclass where I'm calling `QApplication::processEvents()` as long as another instance of `MyMessageBox` is shown:

```
class MyMessageBox : public QMessageBox
{
  public:  
    // omitted (ctor, etc.)

    int exec()
    {
        while( MessageBoxShowingCount > 0 )
            QApplication::processEvents();
        return QMessageBox::exec();
    };

  protected:
    void showEvent( QShowEvent* e )
    {
        MessageBoxShowingCount++;
        QMessageBox::showEvent(e);
    };

    void hideEvent( QHideEvent* e )
    {
        QMessageBox::hideEvent(e);
        MessageBoxShowingCount--;
    };

    static int MessageBoxShowingCount = 0;
};
```

(For this solution I have replaced all my `QMessageBox`-instances by an `MyMessageBox`-instance.)

Comment: All GUI code is single-threaded. The use of synchronization primitives is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to need is an application-wide message manager. The `QMessageBox` then becomes that class's implementation detail and is not used directly anymore. When you want to show a message, you'd then use your `MessageManager` class.

Comment: This would be a nice extension, but the main problem is, that the `processEvents()` inside `QMessageBox::exec()` calls the method which shows the second message box. This is what I wanted to solve and did with my static counter and the own `processEvents()` before calling `QMessageBox::exec()`.

Comment: Don't nest the event loops and you'll be fine. You don't need to call `exec()` in message boxes.

Comment: Kuba Ober: You mean instead I shall use `show()`? But then, how do I get the response code, if I would have a question-message-box?

Comment: The world is asynchronous. Signals are emitted when things happen. Your code should react to these signals.

Comment: So, in cause of Qt uses only one thread (event-loop) for the gui (at least at my windows system), the problem is the `singleShot` in the `showEvent`.
Is there an alternative event like "afterShowEvent" or "widgetCompleteReadyEvent"?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. The message box and its buttons emit signals when interesting things happen. Connect to those signals to manage the progression through the message boxes. Do not even think about threads at this point, because `QWidget`-based GUIs are single-threaded (i.e. all `QWidget`-derived classes live in the main thread).